# Google Apps script getActiveUser.GetEmail(); is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

`var edited = Session.getActiveUser.getEmail();`

this returns "`Session.getActiveUser.getEmail is not a function`"
i do not understand how this works with other users and not me.

i tried:

```
function getEdtiorInfo (cellRange){
  var range = cellRange.range;
  var edited = Session.getActiveUser.getEmail();
   if (editor == '' || editor == null) {
    editor = 'Unknown';
  }
  if (range.getA1Notation().search('G') != -1) {
    range.offset(0, -5).setValue(editor);
  };
}
```

and was expecting to have the cell where this is used to state the person who edited and the time of it.

Comment: there is no method range.  There is getRange().  Also try `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`